Looking for 3D Seed Growing Algorithm (or similar) to generate a uniform anomaly map
I work on 3D MRI images and generate a value at random positions in the image which tells me whether the tissue is healthy or not. I do this for X random positions in the image.
Now I want to generate an anomaly map from these X random positions. So interpolate between the random positions.
Here is a schematic example in 2D to illustrate my problem. The black dots represent the calculated anomaly scores. These should grow in 3D space in such a way that the areas reflect the neighbourhoods as closely as possible.
schematic example in 2D
Above all, I am hoping for keywords that I can search for. Seed growing algorithms is the closest thing I can think of. But as far as I understand it, this is mostly based on a seed. And if there are several seeds, then they don't interact.
I am grateful for any kind of keyword to clarify my internet search. Or ideas on how I can approach the problem.

I am not sure I understood what problem you are trying to solve. It sounds a bit like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

I must have really been on the wrong track with the seeds. Of course, Voronoi diagram. Thank you very very much. That helps me a lot ...
